# How to test non-export function in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have watched many tutorial videos on testing, but usually those tests test passed props to component or uses `data-testid=""`. Is there a way to test non-exported functions? I read about rewire module which does this but problem with that is that Jest will not consider functions called from rewire in coverage reports.

```js
// Random.js
import React from 'react'

export function sayHi() {
  return '';
}

function ListBox() {

  function saySecret() {
    return '';
  }
    
  return (
    <div>ListBox</div>
  )
}

export default ListBox
```

First one which has export would be :

```js
 // Random.test.js
 import { sayHi } from './Random.js';

 describe('sayHi', () => {
   it('returns wave emoji', () => {
     expect(sayHi()).toBe('');
   });
 });
```

How should I test `saySecret`?

Comment: Right now you can't because they're not used

Comment: Testing those functions makes no sense. Don't just blindly follow code coverage. Test functionality. Those aren't used, so there is no functionality to test

Comment: yes 'Function1 ' and 'Function2' are not used here at the moment, i wrote it as example of non exported functions inside component

Comment: We cannot help with code we cannot see. The current example doesn't help here. Please make sure the code is a [mcve]

Comment: _"usually those tests test passed props to component or uses `data-testid=""`"_ - to put it another way, those tests exercise the component _through its public API_. That's what you're _supposed_ to do, otherwise you couple your tests to implementation details rather than behaviour.

Comment: The example isn't clear and doesn't accurately reflect your question

Comment: @evolutionxbox is it now better, i made it more clear ?

Comment: No; less clear, if anything. `saySecret` is totally pointless - it's not _used_ anywhere. You don't need to test it because you can improve coverage, get exactly the same functionality and reduce the maintenance required if you _delete it_. If it was actually _used_, then the answer would be: test it by doing whatever uses it _through the public API_ (e.g. simulating a button click).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't test those functions *in isolation* to the ListBox component itself.

The better answer is that you *shouldn't*. At least the react-testing-library philosophy is:

> you want your tests to avoid including implementation details of your components

https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/

.. and functions that exist only inside a component would very much count as implementation details.

If you need to increase your code coverage, then use react-testing-library to 'use' the component in such a way that the functions are called.

If the functions are reusable bits of code, then move them outside the component, and export them. Then you can test them in the usual way.

Comment: what do you think about this solution:https://www.wisdomgeek.com/development/web-development/javascript/how-to-unit-test-private-non-exported-function-in-javascript/

Comment: scanned that doc. It says: > Note: We should generally not separately test private functions. They are a part of the implementation detail. If a private function behaves incorrectly, then the publicly exposed functions which make use of it would misbehave as well.

Comment: so I'd say *don't* test private functions. test the public bits

Comment: I'm having components which has many functions without export(cant move them outside component), and cannot test them (thats why very low test coverage), does this matter ?

Comment: @walee If they're not used, no. If they are, test the output which uses them

Comment: ofcourse those functions are used but inside a component

Comment: if i test the output, jest still shows in coverage that i need to test that function

Comment: If you absolutely need 100% coverage for whatever reason, you'll need to design Jest tests that *make* the component call the functions, then they'll have coverage